# Securing brick, rock or pavers on artificial turf

Tags: cement, turf

I want to build a backyard putting green. The company I am going to buy the turf from (Garden-mark) says to lay the artificial grass over prepped ground as if laying pavers and secure the turf with spikes.

I would like to add rocks or paver edges (for the golf ball and addition hold down for the turf) and obstacles (like a tunnel), something like this:

[image: Example of what ti might look like]

How would I secure the rock or pavers to each other?  To the turf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We might ask "How are pavers normally secured" and the answer for most parts of this planet is "gravitationally" (there are probably some exceptions in absurdly high wind areas, but "not using pavers" is the most likely approach in those limited areas.)

The turf needs to be secured with spikes because it's not a heavy thing, like a rock or slab of cement (aka paver.) Actual heavy things, particulary low, flat, wide ones, tend to stay where put unless acted on by large outside forces that are uncommon in the extreme (and gluing your rocks down may not help if an F5 tornado comes through, anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat discretionary, but either mortar of the correct type or landscape adhesive should do to bond the stones. I'd think gravity would be adequate to hold it in position on the turf, or you'd install a concrete footing, bond the stone to that, and install turf around it.

Depending on how larger your stones or edgers are you may not need anything.